# WD SmartWare Drive Unlock, Western Digital?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I bought a 1TB Western Digital (USB3) some days ago.
I was using it without any problems, but now whenever I attach it to my laptop USB, the following window  up and I can't use it at all.
The Drive is locked and I can't open it at all.

[image: WD SmartWare Drive Unlock]

How can I fix this and unlock the drive?

**Edit :** 
I just see the following in my computer : 
[image: My Computer]

Comment: Do you see anything in "My Computer"?  Have you password protected your drive?

Comment: See the Edit section in the first post.

Comment: On the original computer see if when you plug it in it works.  If it does, make sure that you "safely remove" it before unplugging.

Comment: Well, how can I find the original computer ? !!!!

Comment: I tested HDD on original computer, We have the problem on original computer.

Comment: @Mohammad You may need to consider wiping the drive...  However please refrain from doing so until the community has agreed that is the only way...

Comment: But I have some important data on it and I don't wanna wipe or format it !!! :-(